# How to get each element in List<JSONObject> json = new ArrayList<JSONObject>()

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I need to get the value in **`ArrayList<JSONObject>()`** as in **`ArrayList<List<String>>()`**

In the case of **`ArrayList<List<String>>`** I have used the following code

```
for(List<String> dreport : report)  {
    for(String ddreport: dreport)   {
        // CODE GOES HERE
    }
}
```

In a new scenario, I need to use the function. But the value is contained in ArrayList() rather than that list of list of string

**SAMPLE CODE:**

```
List<JSONObject> json = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
JSONObject json_data1 = new JSONObject();
json_data1.put("count", "value");
json_data1.put("count", "value");
json_data1.put("count", "value");
json.add(json_data1);
```

Comment: Or else, can i convert **ArrayList<JSONObject>()** to **ArrayList<List<String>>()**

Comment: which json dependency you are using ? `json.org` ?

Comment: Post your sample json string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some alterations in the above answers which will allow it to take up little less space. we don't need to have seprate iterator for keys.

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> jsonObjects = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
//ADD objects in the jsonObjects

ArrayList<List<String>> jsonObjectsResultData = new ArrayList<>();
//Loop for the all JSONObject
for (JSONObject jsonObject : jsonObjects){
    String jsonStr = jsonObject.toString();
    String[] strArr = jsonObject.split(",");

    List<String> jsonObjectsValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<strArr.length;i++){
        jsonObjectsValues.add(strArr[i].split(":")[1]);
    }
    jsonObjectsResultData.add(jsonObjectsValues);
}
//Your result array list
Log.i("RESULT DATA >>", jsonObjectsResultData.toString());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> jsonObjects = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
//ADD objects in the jsonObjects

ArrayList<List<String>> jsonObjectsResultData = new ArrayList<>();
//Loop for the all JSONObject
for (JSONObject jsonObject : jsonObjects){
    Iterator<String> keys= jsonObject.keys();
    List<String> jsonObjectsValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    //Loop for the JSONObject keys and values
    while (keys.hasNext())
    {
        try{
            String keyValue = (String)keys.next();
            String valueString = jsonObject.getString(keyValue);
            jsonObjectsValues.add(valueString);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    jsonObjectsResultData.add(jsonObjectsValues);
}
//Your result array list
Log.i("RESULT DATA >>", jsonObjectsResultData.toString());
```